# Is connect() necessary if I want only to receive data in C/TCP?

Tags: c, tcp, connect

if I want ONLY to receive data from a client, and not send data out, is it necessary have a connect() in the code of my server?

Or is it sufficient to have the following?

```
socket();
bind();
listen();
accept();
```

Comment: @Mat yes I made a mistake, now I've fixed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This describes the basic principle of server-client interaction. As you can see, the client must `connect` to the server before any interaction.

> Once you've built a socket descriptor with the socket() call, you can connect that socket to a remote server using the well-named connect() system call.

Also the sequence you mentioned is in the `server`. If you want to only receive data from server, just do the `read` in client and `write` in server. But `connect` is neccessary.

[image: Server-Client]

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help. So, connect() is not necessary in the server, also if I want to send data from the server to the client?

Comment: No, it is not necessary in any situation. `connect` is used to connect to server from client. The server accepts the `connect request` from client and uses `accept`.

Comment: Now I'm looking at the schema... in a solution of an exercise I've found connect() and bind() in the same function. Is it wrong?

Comment: Usually you don't care what port client uses in `connect`. But if you want to attach client to particular port , follow the sequence `socket` --> `bind` --> `connect`

Comment: Mmh I'm trying to understand. I've also accept() and listen(). Is it possible that this client is used also as a server?

Comment: Maybe but that is not good practice..you just need one server and all others should interact with that one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `socket` and `connect` for the client.

The TCP protocol does send data to the server and recieves data back from the server (even if you are not transferring data) in the form of ACKs

Please read up on the TCP/IP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> if I want ONLY to receive data from a client, and not send data out, is it necessary have a connect() in the code of my server?

It is ***never*** necessary to have connect() in the code of a server.

*Clients* call connect(). Servers call accept(). By definition.